# Deploying Virtualbox via SCCM

Tags: certificate, virtualbox, sccm

Im going to deploy Virtualbox via SCCM and Im curious if there is still necessity to push oracle **certificate** with certuil (separate from instalation)?
If so, how did u get and manage certificate?
I found it in main VirtualBox exe file after instalation, sign it and export it. But Im not sure, if its right way to do so?
I was able to export it from certmgr.msc, but is there any difference if I export it for the user or for the computer?

Also Im curious if there would be any reason to unwrap the **msi** from exe file, if I need to use the batch file anyway?

Thank you in advence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [VirtualBox installation guide](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html) in Section 2.1.4 says to use the standard msi features for unattended installation so I would interpret this as just using /qn for silent or /qb-! for passive. I see nothing regarding any certifiactes so I would assume it is not necessary (in theory it shouldn't be any msi can install a valid certificate imo). If you do it without and find out it was needed or the installer prompts for it despite being silent exporting with certmgr.msc and importing with cerutil is a possible way. As long as there is not private key marked not exportable that is no problem.

Benefits of using msi directly vs. exe depend on the setup, there is no universal answer. Some just do it because it allows for easier deployment via application (SCCM would basically create the whole application for you based on a proper msi) and sometimes the exe is configured to spawn some child process thus terminating which leads to SCCM detecting the installation as finished while it still runs.
(However there are an equal amount of setups where direct msi is not supported or skips all prerequisites and some where both behave exactly the same so you just have to try. When in doubt however and the vendor has a method documented I would just use that one.